# Show time between 2 hours in sql

Tags: php, sql, datetime, mysqli

I have a table which I fill with database info. and this table is as follows

[image]

Next I have table on my overview page which looks like this

[image]

But how can I also add this name at 15:00?

This is the code I use.

```
    $matrix = array();
    // matrix vullen
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
        if ($row['datum_van'] != $date) {
            $date = $row['datum_van'];
            $matrix[$date] = $times;
        }
        $matrix[$date][$row['tijd_van']][] = $row['name'];
        $matrix[$date][$row['tijd_tot']][] = $row['name'];
    }
    // de tabel beginnen
    $var = '<table class="striped">';
    $var .= '<tr class="header" id="ax">';
    $var .= '<td id="a_datum">Datum</td>';

    for($i=9; $i<24; $i++) {

        $var .= '<td>' . $i . ':00</td>';                        
    }
    $var .= '<td>geen eindtijd</td>'; 

    $var .= '</tr>';
    // de matrix uitlezen
    foreach ($matrix as $datekey => $timearray) {
        $var .= '<tr><td>' . $datekey . '</td>';
        foreach ($timearray as $names) {
            $var .= '<td>';
            if (count($names) > 0) {
                $var .= implode('<br>', $names);
            }
            else {
                $var .= '&nbsp;';
            }
            $var .= '</td>';
        }
        $var .= '</tr>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    $var .= '</table>';
    echo $var;
```

Comment: If user is on "meeting" from 14:00 to 16:00, that means that he is on meeting only 2 hours, and not 3, so only hour 14 and 15 should be marked, and not 16. And what happens if from and to are in different days?

Comment: hmm now that u say this it kinda makes sense but what if its from 14:00 to lets say 17:00 then I still need more hours to fill right?

Comment: This is your logic, I am just trying to understand it. If time is from 14:00 to 17:00, 14-15-16 hours should be filled. What if time is 14:00 to 17:15, what hours are filled now? And what happens if from and to dates are in different days? – Glavić 5 mins ago

Answer (score 1):

Based on your method for populating the names into $timearray (the code is not shown), you need to add one more additional check.  You need to check that there exists a name entry where the start time is before the current time, and the end time is after the current time.  A simple check like this will help populate the $timearray correctly:

```
if $cur_time < $time_start and $cur_time > $time_end
    // Add the name to the time-array
```

where $cur_time is the time you are evaluating, and time_start and time_end are the values you have stored in the database table.

Comment: `$timearray` comes from the foreach over `$matrix` which is populated at the beginning of the code

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your full data set... check if the time is greater than (or equal to) the start and less than (or equal to) the end, and if both cases are true, put the person's name in the field.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you only assign those two cells their values with this code

```
$matrix[$date][$row['tijd_van']][] = $row['name'];
$matrix[$date][$row['tijd_tot']][] = $row['name'];
```

You need to check how much time is between those two values `van` and `von` and set names for the hours in between as well.

This could be done the following way

```
$start_timestamp = strtotime($row['tijd_van']);
$scnds_between = strtotime($row['tijd_tot']) - $start_timestamp;
$hrs_between = floor($scnds_between / 3600) - 1;
// -1 because the first hour is already in matrix
for ($i=1; $i<=$hrs_between; ++$i) {
    $new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $start_timestamp+($i*3600));
    $matrix[$date][$new_date][] = $row['name'];
}
```

This only works if `tijd_*` are like the `datum_*` values and can (or modified to) be used with strtotime

Comment: $new_date is empty. because $start_timestap is also empty.. tijd_van is already a time so is strtotime not to much for it ?

Comment: Yes, just remove all the `strtotime` if it already is a valid timestamp

Comment: hmm still no records in the table somehow. I debugged alittle bit and it seems the variables inside the for loop fails to fill.

Comment: Ok, please provide a little more information, e.g. values of `tijd_van`/`tijd_tot`